# Favicon needs to be updated

Tags: joomla, favicon, joomla3.0

Hello I have new joomla 3.0 template but don't know how to change my favicon. 
Did you have the same problem before or can help me with this? So please do.

My website [is](http://www.inspectorgroup.com.au).

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to create a new favicon and upload it to the following directory:

```
root/templates/your_template
```

If you are not able to save your image as an **.ico** file, simply save it as a standard **png** or **jpg** file and use an online converter such as this one:

http://favicon-generator.org/

Once uploaded, if you don't see any changes, force refresh your page using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>